# Difference between getNamedItem() vs getAttribute()?

Tags: javascript, xml

Both give me an attribute of an XML element. Is there any difference between them?

Comment: These options and a third option (`a.b` or `a[c]`) that is available not for all attributes are discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579682/mutationobserver-new-value-in-the-format-of-oldvalue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bookmark the W3C [Document Object Model Core](https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-DOM-Level-1-20000929/level-one-core.html#ID-637646024) - as a source it's as good as it gets.

getAttribute is a method implemented by the [Element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-DOM-Level-1-20000929/level-one-core.html#ID-745549614) interface. From the W3C,

> **getAttribute** Retrieves an attribute value by name.

getNamedItem is a method implemented by the [NamedNodeMap interface](https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-DOM-Level-1-20000929/level-one-core.html#ID-1780488922).  Again from the W3C,

> **getNamedItem** Retrieves a node specified by name.

Clearly getAttribute returns a string whereas getNamedItem returns a *node*, for example, an object implementing the [Attr interface](https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-DOM-Level-1-20000929/level-one-core.html#ID-637646024):

```
interface Attr : Node {
  readonly attribute DOMString        name;
  readonly attribute boolean          specified;
  // Modified in DOM Level 1:
           attribute DOMString        value;
                                        // raises(DOMException) on setting
};
```

I consider getAttribute to be a (huge) convenience method.