# Get the new attribute value for the current MutationRecord when using MutationObserver?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, mutation-observers

I have some code like the following,

```
const observer = new MutationObserver(records => {
    for (const record of records) {
        if (record.type !== 'attributes') continue

        handleAttributeChange(
            record.attributeName!,
            record.oldValue,
            record.target.attributes.getNamedItem(record.attributeName).value,
        )
    }
})
```

where `handleAttributeChange` parameters are the attribute name, the old value, and the new value.

However, as you can tell, the third argument passed into `handleAttributeChange`,

```js
record.target.attributes.getNamedItem(record.attributeName!)!.value
```

is always going to be the very latest attribute value, ***not*** the "new value" for the particular mutation record that we are iterating on (i.e. not the "new value" that was observed at the time that the mutation happened).

How do we get the "new value" for each mutation as would've been observed at the time each mutation happened?

Answer (score 7):

We can emulate that like this:

```js
const observer = new MutationObserver(records => {
    let lastAttributeValues = {}
    let name = ''

    // This loop goes through all the records, and for each mutation,
    // it calls handleAttributeChange with old and new attribute values
    // as would have been observed had we been able to react to each 
    // mutation synchronously.
    for (const record of records) {
        if (record.type !== 'attributes') continue

        name = record.attributeName

        if (lastAttributeValues[name] === undefined) {
            lastAttributeValues[name] = record.oldValue
            continue
        }

        handleAttributeChange(name, lastAttributeValues[name], record.oldValue)

        lastAttributeValues[name] = record.oldValue
    }

    let attr

    // This loop calls handleAttributeChange for each attribute that changed
    // with the last oldValue and the current value that's actually in
    // the DOM (the previous loop handled only differences between each
    // mutation of each mutated attribute, but not the difference between
    // the last mutation of a each attribute and the attributes' current
    // values in the DOM).
    for (const name in lastAttributeValues) {
        attr = el.attributes.getNamedItem(name)
        handleAttributeChange(name, lastAttributeValues[name], attr === null ? null : attr.value)
    }
})
```

What it does is, because we know we get mutations in order, and we have all the attribute values for a given attribute along the way while iterating, it just keeps track of previous and current attribute values (per attribute name) and fires `handleAttributeChange` with each previous and current value.

Comment: Unlike `mutation.target.attributes.getNamedItem(mutation.attributeName)`, the espression `mutation.target.getAttribute(mutation.attributeName)` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70579718/5231110) has the same data format as `mutation.oldValue`. This difference is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44328464/5231110).

Comment: @root that doesn't work. If you have a series of mutations, either of your two expressions return only the latest value, not the "new value" as would have been observed at the time that a particular mutation happened. The question asks "How do we get the 'new value' for each mutation as would've been observed at the time each mutation happened?" and the question even has one of your expressions, and describes why it doesn't work.

Comment: @root I added comments to the code example. The TLDR is that simply reading `mutation.target.attributes.getNamedItem(mutation.attributeName)` or `mutation.target.getAttribute(mutation.attributeName)` is not going to solve the problem.

Comment: It's unbelivable to me on why the Mutationobserver api does not give us the newValue too, why would anyone not include this inside this api...

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's possible with `MutationObserver`. Nothing in a [MutationRecord](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationRecord) exposes the new value, and since a MuationObserver runs in a microtask, and not *completely synchronously* after a change, the value that can be retrieved from the element inside the observer callback may have been changed *after* the change that triggered the observer, as you're seeing.

```js
const observer = new MutationObserver(records => {
  for (const record of records) {
    if (record.type !== 'attributes') continue
    console.log(div.dataset.foo);
    console.log(record);
  }
});
observer.observe(div, { attributes: true });

div.setAttribute('data-foo', 'foo');
div.setAttribute('data-foo', 'bar');
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

While it might have be possible using a *synchronous* observer (listen for the `DOMAttrModified` event on the element), they're deprecated and slow.

If you know how the attribute is going to be changed, you might be able to patch that method so that it goes through your *own* logic first. For example, with `setAttribute`:

```js
div.setAttribute = (...args) => {
  console.log(`Setting ${args[0]} from ${div.getAttribute(args[0])} to ${args[1]}`);
  return HTMLElement.prototype.setAttribute.apply(div, args);
};

div.setAttribute('data-foo', 'foo');
div.setAttribute('data-foo', 'bar');
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I came up with and posted a solution.